# Скрипт работает только при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, fullpage.js

Есть Landing, на котором установлен фрэймворк FullPage.js.

Возникла проблема в том, что некоторые скрипты работают только после перезагрузки страницы. Что нужно сделать?

```js
var ready;

ready = function() {
    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(1)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(4)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(5)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(5)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(6)").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","auto").css("opacity","1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup_block").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $(".photo_content_popup_block img:nth-child(6)").addClass("animated zoomIn faster").css("display","block");
        }, 200);
    });

    $(".photo_content_popup_block img").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup_block img").removeClass("animated zoomIn faster").addClass("animated zoomOut faster").css("display","none");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","none").css("opacity","0");
        }, 200);
        $(".photo_content_popup_block img, .photo_content_popup, .photo_content_pupop_block").removeClass("animated zoomIn zoomOut fadeIn fadeOut faster");
    });

    $(".photo_content_popup .close_button img").click(function(){
        $(".photo_content_popup_block img").removeClass("animated zoomIn faster").addClass("animated zoomOut faster").css("display","none");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".photo_content_popup").css("pointer-events","none").css("opacity","0");
        }, 200);
        $(".photo_content_popup_block img, .photo_content_popup, .photo_content_pupop_block").removeClass("animated zoomIn zoomOut fadeIn fadeOut faster");
    });

    $(".nav-arrow img").click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveSectionDown();
    });

    $(".button-site, .header_head_submit_button, .header_content_left_button").click(function(){
        fullpage_api.moveTo('sixthPage', 0);
    });

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        navigation: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 500,
        responsiveWidth: 900,
        anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'fifthPage', 'sixthPage'],
        afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){
            if(destination.index == 1){
                $(".product_content_img").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                $(".product_content_desc").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".product_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                }, 300);
            }
            
            if(destination.index == 2 || destination.index == 4){
                $(".advantages_content_title").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".advantages_content_desc").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".advantages_content_advant").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".advantages_content_requirement").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $(".advantages_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                            }, 300);
                        }, 300);
                    }, 300);
                }, 300);
            }
            
            if(destination.index == 3){
                $(".product_content_img").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                $(".product_content_desc").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".product_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                }, 300);

                $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(1), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(2), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".photo_content_title").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(4), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(5), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(6)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".photo_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                    }, 200);
                }, 200);
            }
            
            if(origin.anchor == "thirdPage"){
                $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(1), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(2), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(3)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".photo_content_title").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".photo_content_galery img:nth-child(4), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(5), .photo_content_galery img:nth-child(6)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".photo_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                    }, 200);
                }, 200);
            }
            
            if(origin.anchor == "fourthPage" || origin.anchor == "sixthPage"){
                $(".about_content .who").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".about_content p").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".about_content h3").addClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".about_content .advantage:nth-child(1)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                        }, 100);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".about_content .advantage:nth-child(2)").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                        }, 100);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".about_content_button").addClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                        }, 200);
                    }, 200);
                }, 200);
            } 

            if( $(".contacts").hasClass("active") ){
                $(".nav-arrow").css("display","none");
            } else {
                $(".nav-arrow").css("display","flex");
            }
        },
        onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".product_content_img").removeClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                $(".product_content_desc").removeClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".product_content_button").removeClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".advantages_content_title, .advantages_content_desc, .advantages_content_advant, .advantages_content_requirement, .advantages_content_button").removeClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".photo_content_galery img").removeClass("animated fadeInDown fadeInUp faster");
                $(".photo_content_title").removeClass("animated fadeInDown faster");
                $(".photo_content_button").removeClass("animated fadeInUp faster");
                $(".about_content .who, .about_content p, .about_content h3, .about_content .advantage, .about_content_button").removeClass("animated fadeInDown fadeInUp faster").css("opacity","0");
            }, 300)
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(ready);

$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Было, что-то подобное. Решилось закачкой js скрипта в папку с сайтом(js/FullPage.js) это в случаи если вы подключаете js с другого сайта.

Comment: Как скрипт подключается? Возможно код выполняется уже после загрузки страницы => событие onload больше не будет. А после перезагрузки скрипты запускаются из кэша быстрее

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что при запуске страницы и выполнении скриптов возникала какая-то ошибка, которая останавливала остальное. В моём случае в начале обрабатывался скрипт, который вешает событие на окошко об ошибке, которое не появляется при запуске страницы, а лишь после неудачного действия, а тогда и при первичном выполнении файла со скриптами не появится ошибка и всё будет норм.

Проверить где конкретно ошибка можно открыв консоль в dev tools браузера.